# How can I quickly adjust “Do Not Disturb” - “Allow Calls From” in iOS?

Tags: ios, do-not-disturb

I like to adjust which contacts can call me when “Do Not Disturb” is active, but going deep into the settings each time is tedious. Is there a faster way to adjust this setting?

Answer (score 1):

Long hold on the “Do Not Disturb” icon in control center, and select “Schedule”.

This will take you directly to the “Do Not Disturb” settings, where you can make any desired adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Shortcuts app to maintain a separate group of whitelisted contacts that are allowed to bypass Do Not Disturb (you can choose to Allow Calls From a group). That way, you can introduce more complicated behavior into the shortcut - for example, "toggle all family members", or "only allow my wife" - through a menu system within the shortcut. You can also trigger the shortcut from a home screen icon, Siri, Apple Watch, or back tap.

Note that you'll need to create the group in iCloud or Google Contacts (whichever sync service you use) first, as you can't create groups in the native Contacts app.

[image: Shortcuts App showing a shortcut that adds the 'Whitelisted' group to John Smith]